# Tomcat to Glassfish url

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, web-applications

Let's say I have a Tomcat and a web application on it with `index.html` is in `catalina_home\webapps\ROOT\index1.html` and this web application runs successfully to the internet.

Also I have a glassfish with another application deployed on it with let's say an index2.jsp.

Can I have a link in index1 that can open index2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just let the `href` attribute of the link point to that URL.

E.g.

```
<a href="http://example.com/index2.jsp">Click here to get to index2.jsp</a>
```

To learn more about using links in HTML, check [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).